# Trying to retrieve email id from SQLiteDatabase Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a signup activity in which user provides email id and i save their email id in SQLiteDatabase. Before saving email id i am checking if email id already present in database. Below is the code i am using to check. But the problem here it is always returning false means shows email Id already present. Kindly help.

```
public boolean readUser(String email){
        sqLiteDatabase = userDatabaseUtility.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COLUMN_EMAIL + " = '" + email + "'";
        Log.i("LOG", selectQuery);

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor != null){
            // email already exist
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor could be empty but not null. Instead of having

```
if(cursor != null) {
      // email already exist
      cursor.close();
      return false;
} else {
      return true;
}
```

you should just have

```
return cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0;
```

if you have an entry with that email it returns `true` otherwise it returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

An empty cursor will not be `null`. You should instead check if `cursor.getCount() > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Cursor will not be null as you have made an assignment. You have to check if `cursor.getCount()` is greater than 0 which means cursor has found atleast one match for your email address.

```
   if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        // email already exist 
        cursor.close();
        return false; 
    } else { 
        return true; 
    }
```